# System UI Tuner not enabling

Tags: lenovo

How do I enable System UI Tuner on my Lenovo Vibe K4 Note.
It is not enabling on long press of quick settings button in the notification panel.

Comment: Long press and hold for a while ?

Comment: It is possible Lenovo disabled it in their ROM... If you Google your model and System UI tuner, others have not been able to enable it either.

Answer (score -1):

if you are on marshmallow long press the "GEAR" icon for 5 seconds

[image]

(you should see a prompt that says ui tuner enabled)
[image]

then go to settings and you should see the ui tuner in the settings.
[image]

Link with tutorial here http://gadgetguideonline.com/android/android-marshmallow-guide/how-to-use-system-ui-tuner-in-android-marshmallow/

Comment: Considering that manufacturer can customize and enable/disable some features, are you sure this is possible on Lenovo Vibe K4 Note?

Comment: @AndrewT. this is a valid point in this case i would suggest Rooting and running a custom Rom. some rom's for this device could be found here https://forum.xda-developers.com/f/lenovo-vibe-k4-note-roms-kernels-recoveries-o.5856/